# Hide the Form View in OpenErp (formally as Odoo)

Tags: openerp-7, openerp-8, odoo

**How can I hide the Form View Based on User Access**

I have created one user (student) in school Management System in openerp.
The Admin user is the default user in OpenErp. Admin have  all the access rights to acees the Tree view and Form View while How can I restrict the the student user to view only 
tree view.

My Question is how can i hide the Form View When the student user is logged into the system.I wanted to display  only the the tree view when he or she is logged into the system while admin can display both the view like form and tree.

Comment: You can create security in .csv file throw user and group wise different permission.

Comment: @JainikPatel this is not the right way to do so it is not solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Okay for that you have to assign a groups.

- First of all please create a group from Setting->Users->Groups
- Then on creating group, click on access write where you have to add your object and give whatever access write you have to give
- Then add users to a particular group.
  [image]
  [image]

Comment: I had already created on group and also add the two different user in to the group like admin and student(normal user) also add the access rights for that object like exam.master(object name) but problem doesn't solve it

Comment: As I have stated above I have tried using project/task and my side it working properly. Try adding only student user.May be it could not happens because of admin or I am just guessing.

Comment: Sorry by adding admin also its working on my side. Are you tried by logging as student. Because its working here.

Comment: how to do this for the student user..??

Comment: Just create new user student then add student to the group and then logged in as a student. It will definitely work. For just example you can even try on demo user.

Comment: Okay, If you got it please make it as answer.