# OpenERP security for a specific user

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, openerp-8

All my seniors, I have a security rule for Human Resources Employee and Contract.
If user is manager role, user can see all data in contract including wage (salary). Otherwise, if user is assistance HR role, she can see all contract data except employee wage.
Can I hide (invisible) fields in OpenERP with related security? Can I create a security rule like that? Need any access right mechanism.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you try to format your question to make it more readable - currently it is like a wall of text. Also, can you show what you have tried in terms of research and implementation so far, and what results that gave you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the XML side of this field wage, you just need to add the manager group. For example:

```
<field name="wage" groups="base.group_hr_manager"/>
```

Now only the user having the HR manager permission can see this field. No others will be able to see this

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it in OpenERP. Apps have already common access rights to use for security purpose. but even you can modify for particular users.

For that you have to use GROUPS. Groups is specific group of people can assign some specific validations. I have already answered regarding this. You can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24401044/hide-the-form-view-in-openerp-formally-as-odoo/24402580#24402580)

Comment: I mean for wage only.Mananger can see wage field and assistant can't see it.

Comment: I think for that you have to develop single group because there is not any particular access right define in it.

Comment: Could you explain me with code .I don't know how i do?Thanks

Comment: Can I make invisible/visible for wage with particular login user.